# Flex Security Error Accessing URL

Tags: apache-flex, web-services

I had this error in a Flex Application that I couldn’t figure out.
Every time the app attempted to access the Web Service it returned the error 
“Security Error Accessing URL”.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing the web service independent of the flex application?
Maybe there is something wrong with the web service itself.

Comment: Do i need to add crossdomain.xml in server?

Comment: my webservice is in server.when i am running through IIS then it gives the security error.

Comment: From what I know in order to access remote data sources within a flash player is if one of the three conditions are met: 1. A cross domain file is present in the same domain as the data source. 2. The compiled swf is in the same domain as the data source. 3. A proxy is used, and the swf file is on the same server as the proxy. A crossdomain file is a way to go, but I thing the easiest(if possible in your case) is number 2.

Comment: yes complied swf file is in the same domain.but i am accessing webservice(in same domain) through ip address in my server.

Comment: here is my crossdomain.xml 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false" />
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>

Comment: my crossdomain.xml ,  webservice is also in my server root .Is there ny changes req. to crossdomain.xml